# How can I set max upload size in symfony2 sonata media while uploading Image

Tags: symfony, media, sonata

How can I set max upload size in symfony2 sonata media while uploading Image via Sonata media Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inline validation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/reference/conditional_validation.html) in each admin class or set this constraint in your php.ini:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 5M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 10M
```